# Spark SQL - Column is available after drop

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to understand why I can filter on a column that I have previously dropped.

This simple script:

```scala
package example

import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col

object Test {

    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        val spark = SparkSession.builder()
            .appName("Name")
            .master("local[*]")
            .config("spark.driver.host", "localhost")
            .config("spark.ui.enabled", "false")
            .getOrCreate()
        
        import spark.implicits._

        List(("a0", "a1"), ("b0", "b1"))
            .toDF("column1", "column2")
            .drop("column2")
            .where(col("column2").startsWith("b"))
            .show()
    }
}
```

Shows the folliwing output:

```
+-------+
|column1|
+-------+
|     b0|
+-------+
```

I expected to see some error that "column2" is not available when I try to use it in `.where(<condition>)`.

Snippet from my `build.sbt`:

```scala
scalaVersion := "2.12.10"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.4.4" excludeAll ExclusionRule("org.apache.hadoop")
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-client" % "3.2.1"
```

Is there some documentation on this behaviour? And why is it even possible?

Comment: It's a known issue in spark, look here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-30421

Comment: and here https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/27128

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because sparks pushes the filter/predicate, i.e. spark optimizes the query in such a way that the filter is applied before the "projection". The same occures with `select` instead of `drop`.

This can be beneficial because the filter can be pushed to the data:

[image]